# WebDriverException with geckodriver for selenium in docker and jupyter

Tags: python, docker, selenium, jupyter, geckodriver

I use windows10, docker and jupyter and tried to run selenium with the geckodriver for firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

but everytime it shows

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
`WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

even though i put the directory in the PATH.
geckodriver.exe is in the folder:
C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker
and i put the folder and the directory C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker\geckodriver.exe in the PATH.
I also tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "geckodriver")
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker")
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker': 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker' executable needs to be in PATH.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker\geckodriver.exe")
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker\geckodriver.exe': 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker\geckodriver.exe'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Programs\Docker\geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/path/to/geckodriver')
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/geckodriver': '/path/to/geckodriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: `webdriver.Firefox()` you never added the path to the webdriver: `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')`

Comment: i tried the code and get the same error

Comment: If you got the same error then you did not enter the correct path to the geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

That's because selenium doesn't know where the driver is.

You need to download the driver from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/), copy the driver on your project folder (or anywhere you want really), and use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
```

I would suggest reading the documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/installing_browser_drivers/) first.

Comment: i tried the code and get the same error

Comment: @caiolucas update the question with your code. It seems you're writing the path in the wrong way